# Javascript literal functions

Tags: javascript, function, google-maps, literals

I have a problem with Javascript Literal functions.

```
    for (curitem in array)
    {
        var tl = new GTileLayer(copyrightCollection, 0, 21 );

        tl.getTileUrl = function(a, b)  { 
                return MyFunction(a, b, curitem); 
            };

        ...

        secondArray.push(tl);
    }
```

The problem is: When "MyFunction" is called, the third parameter has always the **last value**  used in function creation (values are like 0,1,2,3,4,6 and I always receive 6).

How can I solve this?

Thank you

Comment: Answering the question is easy, but won't solve the problem. What are you intending should happen? Why are you recreating `tl` for every `curitem`?

Comment: if `array` is an actual `Array` and not an `Object`, using `for..in` is a bad idea! Use `for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)` instead!

Comment: I recreate it because I have different tile urls (I have to load many customer defined data on map).

Comment: array is an object I receive in JSON from customer's server, not a classical Array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Classic problem with loops and closures. You can easily solve it by creating a new variable every loop, e.g. by using an anonymous function and passing the value as a parameter:

```
for (var curitem in array) {
    var tl = new GTileLayer(copyrightCollection, 0, 21);

    (function(curitem) {
        tl.getTileUrl = function(a, b) { 
            return MyFunction(a, b, currentitem); 
        };
    })(curitem);

    // ...

    secondArray.push(tl);
}
```